# Maximizer of bivariate function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have a problem with seems quite easy, but I can't figure out what I am missing to solve it.

> Let?? $U : \Bbb R_0^+ \times \Bbb R_0^+ \to \Bbb R^+$ be defined by $$ U (x,y) := 4 \sqrt{2x+4y} -2x-3y $$ Find the value for $x$ and $y$, such that $U$ is maximized.

---

$x$ and $y$ should be $\ge 0$.  I tried to solve for $\frac{\partial U}{\partial x} = 0$ and $\frac{\partial U}{\partial y} = 0$, where

$$ \begin{aligned} \frac {\partial U}{\partial x} &= \frac {4}{\sqrt{2x+4y}} - 2 \\\\
 \frac{\partial U}{\partial y} &= \frac {8}{\sqrt{2x+4y}} - 3 \end{aligned} $$

Next I tried to solve this systems of equations to obtain x and y, which leads to

$$ \begin{aligned} 2x + 4y &= 4 \\ 2x + 4y &= \frac{64}{9} \end{aligned} $$

and this is where I get stuck, because this does not lead to the right answer, where $ x = 0, y = \frac{16}{9}$ and $ U = \frac {16}{3} $. What is the right approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Note that turning points should satisfy 
$$
2x + 4y = 4, \\
2x + 4y = \frac{8^2}{3^2}.
$$

Comment: You want to find the maximum local or global? Are you sure that you don't have any constraint?

Comment: Why did you introduce the `$$`?

Comment: @JK7 How would you choose $x,y$ in such a way that $2x+4y$ is simultaneously equal to $4$ and $64/9$ ? \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any local maximizer can only occur at:

1. A stationary point in the set $D=\{(x,y): x>0, y>0\}$
2. a point in boundary of $D$.

Since there are no stationary points, our analysis reduces to 2.

a) $U(x,0) = 4 \sqrt{2x} - 2x$ attains a maximum at $x = 2$.

b) $U(0,y) = 4\sqrt{4y} - 3y$ attains a maximum at $y=\frac{16}{9}$.

Since $u(2,0) = 4$ and $u(0,\frac{16}{9}) = \frac{16}{3}$, the global maximum is attained at $(0,\frac{16}{9})$.

---

Note: the stationary points would be solutions of
$$
\frac{4}{\sqrt{2 x+4 y}} = 2, \quad \frac{8}{\sqrt{2 x+4 y}} = 3
$$

Since there are no solutions to this system, there are no stationary points.

Comment: The only constraint is that x and y should be greater than or equal to 0. I hope that that answers your question if I am correctly understanding what you are meaning

Comment: Just a small remark: $U(x=0, y=16/9)=16/3$.Since the OP realized the correction after your answer I understand the reason to consider $U(x=-100,y=50)$, but after the correction we can't evaluate in $x<0$ axis.

Comment: But it should not be looked at for x < 0, so I am not quite understanding what you are meaning.

Comment: @JK7 Why not? As long as you remain within the domain, there is no reason (unless stated otherwise) to rule out negative values for $x$. anyway, I edited my answer to include the restrictiions $x\ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I thought that I added the constraint which stated that x and y have to be > 0. I made an edit to the original post

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion that there are no stationary points in the set?

Comment: @JK7 Because $\sqrt{2x+4y}$ can't be simultaneously  2 and $\frac 83$. The same goes to your linear system...